# Finding the conditional probability of 3 variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The question is:

> P(Z,X)= 0.25
>
> P (X)= 0.2
>
> P(Y)= 1
>
> P(Z|X)= 0.6
>
> P(Z|Y)= 0.4
>
> Find P(Z| X,Y).

I have 2 problems:

1. If P(Z|X)= 0.6 and using the conditional probability formula, shouldn't P(Z, X)= 0.12 but the probability given by the question is =0.2?
2. If I wish to use the conditional probability formula to find P(Z| X,Y), how do I go about finding P(X,Y,X) and P(X,Y)? Else, is there any other formulas/methods that I can use to find P(Z| X,Y)?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes: $\mathsf P(X)=0.2, \mathsf P(Z\mid X)=0.6,$ and $\mathsf P(X,Z)=0.25$ is *inconsistent* with the definition of conditional probability, which requires that:  $\mathsf P(X,Z)=\mathsf P(X)\,\mathsf P(X\mid Z)$.   At least *one* from these values is erroneous.
2. Notice that $\mathsf P(Y)=1$ means that event $Y$ is certain.

Comment: 2. so given that P(Y)=1, does it mean that P(X,Y,Z)= P(X,Z) and P(X,Y)= P(X)?

Comment: Most surely so.